# Paddle OCR gives "device id must be less than GPU count" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, ocr, paddleocr

I am trying to use Paddle OCR for reading numbers from images, but it gives me this error:

"(InvalidArgument) Device id must be less than GPU count, but received id is: 0. GPU count is: 0.
[Hint: Expected id < GetGPUDeviceCount(), but received id:0 >= GetGPUDeviceCount():0.] (at ..\paddle\phi\backends\gpu\cuda\cuda_info.cc:242)"

The error comes from this line of code : `ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')`

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I can't find the solution on the internet.

This is the code that I am using:

```
# Paddleocr supports Chinese, English, French, German, Korean and Japanese.
# You can set the parameter `lang` as `ch`, `en`, `french`, `german`, `korean`, `japan`
# to switch the language model in order.
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en') # need to run only once to download and load model into memory
img_path = 'capture.png'
result = ocr.ocr(img_path, cls=True)
for idx in range(len(result)):
    res = result[idx]
    for line in res:
        print(line)

# draw result
from PIL import Image
result = result[0]
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
boxes = [line[0] for line in result]
txts = [line[1][0] for line in result]
scores = [line[1][1] for line in result]
im_show = draw_ocr(image, boxes, txts, scores, font_path='/path/to/PaddleOCR/doc/fonts/simfang.ttf')
im_show = Image.fromarray(im_show)
im_show.save('result.jpg')`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value of PaddleOCR for GPU is True, you would need to disable it if you don't have GPU.

```
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en', use_gpu=False)
```